# eclipse how to access the Android Device from Remote machine

Tags: android, eclipse

My scenario is this: I have a work computer with Windows 8 at my home and I use eclipse as my development environment for Android apps. I would like to be able to deploy apps from my work computer on android device my friend located in some other country and execute the Android emulator. Finally I want to remotely access and debug the app installed on friend device.

How can I do it remotely?

Answer (score 0):

Can be done, but may require following, there is one limitation though, that you cant directly access the device to test the app, your friend will have to do that.

1. The Device and your Work Computer needs to be connected using VPN under same network or the device must have its port(explained in 2nd step) for adb port-forwarded through the router, if you want to connect to the device directly through the IP(but this can be risky).
2. In order to run Device debugger in TCPIP Mode execute the following command, where 5555 is the port number at which the android debugger of device can be accessed, this command need to executed after connecting the device to the your friend's computer.

   `adb tcpip 5555`
3. Once the device and Work Computer are connected over the vpn, or the Device is port-forwarded on the port used in the above command, execute the command on your Work Computer. In the below Syntax the IP is the Device IP and the Port is the port number mentioned in the command in 2nd step.

   `Syntax: adb connect IP:port`

   `Example: adb connect 10.2.10.251:5555`
4. Now you can, install and debug the device over the internet, but there may be delays uploading the apk and get the debug result.
5. In order to disconnect the device, execute on your Work Computer.

   adb disconnect

Comment: This is not under the same network. Can you describe me how can I connect to the device directly using VPN ?

Comment: assuming that you know how to setup VPN, refer to this [link](http://www.ibvpn.com/billing/knowledgebase/23/How-to-setup-personal-PPTP-VPN-on-Android-phonesuu.html) in order to connect the Android device to VPN.